# ¿Algún sistema de comunicación en tiempo real entre programas que corren en un mismo computador?

Tags: arquitectura-de-software

Estoy haciendo un bot que está compuesto de varios bots, cada uno escrito en un lenguaje de programación distinto. Ahora solo tengo python y voy a meter próximamente js corriendo en a través de node, pero me gustaría añadir otros bots escritos en java y c++.
Se me ocurre que para comunicar programas que se encuentran en diferentes computadores puedo recurrir al protocolo http, websockets o cualquir otra cosa inventada hasta ahora para hacer posible Internet, pero **¿Cómo puedo hacer para comunicar programas que están dentro de un mismo computador?** Se me ocurre que puedo montar varios servidores en una misma máquina, uno por bot y habilitar un puerto para cada bot y que se manden entre ellos mensajes por los correspondientes puertos habilitados. También se me ocurre que puedo crear un fichero donde vayan escribiendo todos los programas y que a su vez pueda ser leído por los mismos o cualquier forma de reservar una porción de memoria de la RAM que sirva como "buzón", tiene que ser de la RAM porque en un disco duro mecánico creo que ralentizaría la comunicación entre mis bots y por tanto su funcionamiento en conjunto. Me da la impresión de que puede haber algo más rápido aún y tal vez más directo. En la universidad ví una asignatura llamada "Sistemas informáticos en tiempo real" y nos contaron un recurso de linux para mandar mensajes entre programas, pero no sé si solo era para programas escritos en c, o tal vez supogo que al tratarse de un recurso del sistema operativo, no importa el lenguaje en el que esté escrito tu programa. La verdad es que la comunicación entre programas es interesante porque si se pudieran comunicar de forma directa entre ellos tal vez no se necesitaría el sistema operativo, siempre y cuando siguieran un protocolo para gestionar de forma descentralizada la utilización de recursos como memoria y cpu entonces un SO podría ser sustituido por un protocolo pero volviendo a mi pregunta, la haré una vez más **¿Alguién sabe técnicas o estrategias no mencionadas en este post para comunicar programas (preferiblemente escritos en lenguajes de programación diferentes ) entre sí?.**

Comment: Te recomendaría leer [ask], me parece una pregunta muy amplia y que por lo mismo puede no ajustarse al formato del sitio y culminar cerrada

Comment: gracias @BetaM: Pues matizaré mi pregunta desde este comentario: ¿Alguién puede mencionar al menos una técnica o estrategia para comunicar programas entre si que se encuentran dentro de un mismo computador?Creo que así bastará porque mi pregunta no demanda que me contesten con la Biblia de la arquitectura del software, sección comunicación entre programas. Tan solo que me mencionen una sola opción, no necesito conocer todas las opciones disponibles. De todas formas me voy a leer ese post de como preguntar (no sería la primera vez que lo hago)

Comment: sockets, pipes, memoria compartida... yo iria por sockets

Comment: @abulafia: Muchas gracias! Me has ayudado a encontrar términos con los cuales organizar mis ideas y mi búsqueda. Te agradecería que me editases una respuesta para poder validarla y dar por zanjada esta cuestión.

Comment: @Mr.Baldan Pues hecho. Y aproveché para explayarme un poco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas se llama de forma genérica IPC (*Inter-Process Communication*). Las facilidades de IPC que te da cada operativo pueden variar. Te comento las que conozco para Linux. No sé si Windows tiene lo mismo u otras equivalentes.

- Si se trata simplemente de hacer esperar un proceso por otro, puedes usar semáforos o mutexes.
- Si se trata de compartir un valor con otro proceso puedes utilizar memoria compartida (cada proceso recibiría un puntero a una zona de memoria que resulta ser la misma para ambos). Este mecanismo debe ser sincronizado de alguna forma (de nuevo usando semáforos o mutexes) para evitar que un proceso esté escribiendo mientras otro está leyendo, o para evitar que uno se ponga a leer antes de que el otro haya escrito nada. Esto se considera un mecanismo de bajo nivel y difícil de usar bien, son preferibles otros.
- Usando *pipes* puedes beneficiarte de la API de ficheros y de sincronización automáticamente manejada por el operativo. Ambos procesos abrirían el mismo *pipe*, uno para escribir, otro para leer. Lo que un proceso escribe en el *pipe* el otro lo recibe. El que lee del *pipe* se bloquea si no hay nada, hasta que el que escribe haya puesto algo en él.
- También puedes usar *sockets*, que son un mecanismo genérico de comunicación. Puedes usar sockets "tipo unix" (que son implementados internamente en el operativo usando memoria compartida, por lo que son muy rápidos y eficientes), o sockets "tipo TCP/IP", que usan el *stack* de comunicaciones de la máquina. Estos últimos tienen como ventaja que si en el futuro decides separar los procesos a diferentes máquinas, no tendrás que cambiar nada en el código (sólo en la IP a la que se conectan).
- Además, tienes soluciones como sistemas de mensajería por colas (rabbitmq) o almacenes clave-valor compartidos (redis), que consistirían en delegar en un proceso aparte la tarea de almacenar los datos a compartir y su distribución entre los procesos interesados en recibirlos. Conectarías con estas aplicaciones usando sus respectivas APIs, para lo que necesitarías sus librerías para cada uno de los lenguajes que vayas a usar. Esta solución es muy flexible al *desacoplar* los procesos que generan datos de los que los reciben.

Yo usaría sockets por ser lo más genérico y hasta cierto punto lo más sencillo. En cualquier caso, cualquiera que sea el método que uses, vas a necesitar manejar adecuadamente la concurrencia, lo que no es tarea sencilla. Querrás seguramente que un proceso pueda seguir haciendo otras cosas mientras no reciba información de otros procesos, en lugar de quedarse bloqueado esperando por esa información. Eso te obligará a programar con *multihilo* en cada proceso, y tener un hilo dedicado a las comunicaciones mientras otros hilos se dedican a otras cosas. Y tendrás que sincronizar esos hilos entre sí. Otra opción es utilizar programación asíncrona, lo cual también tiene su dificultad porque te obliga a cambiar la manera de pensar sobre el flujo de tu programa.

Comment: Excelente comentario, muchas gracias!